# Remove portion of header code from home page only

Tags: templates, headers, get-template-part

I have this code in the template file `header.php`:

```
<div class="dynamic-header">
    <?php if(function_exists('show_media_header')){ show_media_header(); } ?>
</div>
```

I want to process that header info on all pages, except for homepage. How I can do this?

Comment: I found that WP offers API to do this: <?php 
       if (is_front_page() ) {
               get_header( 'front' );

        } else {
               get_header();
       }
?>

Comment: Post your solution as an actual answer please, then mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple conditional statements:

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'show_media_header' ) 
    and ! is_home() // list of newest blog posts
    and ! is_front_page() // front page, might be a static page
)
{ 
    show_media_header(); 
} 
?>
```

You don’t need a separate file for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate file, just do:

```
<? if (!is_front_page()){ ?>
<div class="dynamic-header"><?php if(function_exists('show_media_header')){ show_media_header(); } ?></div><?
}
?>
```